# jQuery .each() inside blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am new in jQuery and just learning. I have Incorrect code  that works fine! But according to the rules of the jQuery this is a big mistake. So it is impossible to do. I dislike write code like this.  Also I have function inside another!

I think everything is wrong with me. Can somebody help and show right way?

```
$('input[name="username"]')
  .blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    $('span#username    ').addClass('input--filled')
  }
  if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    $('span#username' +
      '').removeClass('input--filled')
  } else {
    //Nothing at the moment
  }
});
```

And for second input the same code but with another selectors

```
$('input[name="first_name"]')
  .blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    $('span#first_name    ').addClass('input--filled')
  }
  if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    $('span#first_name').removeClass('input--filled')
  } else {
    //Nothing at the moment
  }
});
```

Really I can not write same for other all 5 inputs. That is wrong! I have to check all the input like that.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: I think there is all you need to answer the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the third `conditional` block.

```
else {
   //Nothing at the moment
}
```

because the first `two` covers all **cases**.

```
$('input').blur(function() {
  let name=$(this).attr('name');
  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    $('span#'+name).addClass('input--filled')
  }
  if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    $('span#'+name).removeClass('input--filled')
  }
});
```

Comment: That is worked for all fields except password field? Why?

Comment: @jinjer2, maybe password fields don't have name property.

Answer (score 1):

### You can do this a lot easier.

The else is not needed and we're gonna use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). This does the same as your code:

```
$('#username').blur(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('input--filled', this.value.length >= 1);
});
```

**Changes I've made:**

- First, the `if`/`if`/`else` doesnt work. If you want that logic, use `if`/`else if`/`else`. Also, you do not need an empty else. `if(justIf=="noElse"){}` is fine.
- Changes `span#username` to `#username`. When using ID's, use the ID only, as this enables jquery to use javascripts `getElementById()` which is extremely fast.
- Changed `input[name="username"]` to `#username` and the inner `#username` to `this`. In a function, `this` refers to the element on which the event is fired (here, the blurred input). By using `this` you dont have to retype your selector and your code because easier to maintain.
- Instead of `$(this).val()` you can use `this.value`. Instead of using the *function* `.val()`, you now select the plain javascript object and use it's property `.value`. For inputs, this is very useful because properties are always superfast.
- I've used [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). The 2nd parameter makes you control the toggle. If it's true, you add the class. If its false, you remove the class. We just place the length login there et voila.

---

If you want to use this on multiple inputs, use this code (and remember the part about `this`):

```
// Add a class to all elements you want this logic to be on.
$('.lengthChecker').blur(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('input--filled', this.value.length >= 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a one-to-one mapping between the `<input>` element's `name` attribute and the span's `id` attribute, you can simply use the following code:

```
// Select all inputs with `name` attribute
$('input[name]').blur(function() {

  // Target is defined by the input's name attribute
  var target = $(this).attr('name');

  // The targeted span element is identified by ID
  var $targetedSpan = $('#' + target);

  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    $targetedSpan.addClass('input--filled')
  }

  if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    $targetedSpan.removeClass('input--filled')
  } else {
    //Nothing at the moment
  }
});
```

Some tips to your code:

- You don't need to use `span#id`, since ID is unique within the document. Using `#id` selector is more than sufficient
- You should cache your span selector, so that we don't have to query the DOM all the time when we want to add/remove class. That is why I have stored the targeted span in the `$targetedSpan` variable, instead of reusing `$('#' + target)` twice

Answer (score 0):

Your can try something like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
  .blur(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val().length >= 1) {
    $('span#' + $this.attr("name")).addClass('input--filled')
  }
  if ($this.val().length < 1) {
    $('span#'+ $this.attr("name")).removeClass('input--filled')
  } else {
    //Nothing at the moment
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Welcome to StackOverflow!* You can create a function that wraps your code but instead of having fixed values, you are going to use a variable to know what field you are preparing.

Here is an example. I use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` and `removeClass`, because you can write a condition for the second parameter.

```js
// I guess the easiest way is to add a certain class
// to your input field instead of checking for a specific name.
$( 'input.checkValue' ).blur( checkInputValue );

function checkInputValue( event ) {
  // We just use the event to get the fields name
  // and we use toggleClass to get rid of the if-conditions
  //
  // When ( event.target.value.length > 0 ) is true, .input--filled
  // is going to be added, otherwise removed.
  $( 'span#' + event.target.name )
    .toggleClass( 'input--filled', event.target.value.length > 0 );
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c41e15;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.input--filled {
  background: #61c415;
}

/* Just some style for the field row */
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <input name="username" class="checkValue" />
  <span id="username"></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <input name="someOtherField" class="checkValue" />
  <span id="someOtherField"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you script and shortened it. You can use many selectors in a query select, separated by `comma`. And I use a technique called "`ternary operator`" to toggle the class accordingly.

**Here is a working fiddle:**

```js
$('input[name="username"], input[name="first_name"]').blur(function() {
 var span = $('#' + $(this).prop('name'));
 span.removeClass('input--filled').addClass(($(this).val().length >= 1) ? 'input--filled' : '');
});
```

```css
.input--filled{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="username">Username</span>
<input name="username" type="text">

<span id="first_name">First Name</span>
<input name="first_name" type="text">
```